# connect to windows azure database from VS 2012 Express

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have been following this example 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/

and I could not connect to windows azure database.  It gives me the following error
"A network-related error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible."

I have the IP address set, and made a firewall role already.

Any ideas :(

Answer (score 0):

First test whether your ISP (Internet Provider) or corporate system administrator is not blocking outgoing connections on port 1433! This is very common issue with accessing SQL Azure  from own laptop/computer.

To test firewall setting just navigate to the web management portal for your SQL Azure Instance. It has a default address:

`https://[your_server_name].database.windows.net/?langid=en-us`

This will open web management (Silverlight) portal for your SQL Azure Server. You can use to test whether you have correctly configured Firewall Rules on the Azure side. If you have done so, you will be able to log-in from the browser. Note that even if it uses the browser the management portal still respects the Firewall rules for the SQL Azure database.

If cannot log-in from the SQL Azure management portal, then check again your **real** IP address and make sure it matches the firewall rules.

If you can login from the portal, but not from Visual Studio - then check with your system administrators (or Internet provider support line) whether they have blocked outgoing connections on port 1433. If this is the case you cannot do anything, but just work from the web portal.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think that might be it. The Internet provider blocked outgoing connections on port 1433.